# Normalize weekly data - Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a weekly dataset and I have to normalize this data. 
Data is something like this :

```
1. week   50
2. week   51
3. week   50
4. week   54
5. week   150
6. week   155
7. week   ...
```

The important thing is, the difference between week 3 and week 4 (50-54) is not same with week 5 and week 6. And also there is a huge different between week 4 and week 5.

My question is how can i handle all of this things ?

Is the standard normalization functions(for example scikit normalization) can do it for me and should I normalize this data 0-1 or -1 to 1 ?

[Sklearn normalization page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

**NOTE** I am working with python and generally scikit-learn library.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What range you normalise to would depend on what you wish to do with the transformed data.

Answer (score 1):

I would find the unit variance of the all the weeks and then divide by that. Scikit can do this for you using [scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html).

Comment: Could you please explain more detaily. I will give the list of my data(an array) to scale() function and it will return an array. Then should I divide my real list of data to the other array(which is the result of scale) ?